# Jquery slider setinterval not working.

Tags: jquery, image, slider

What is a problem with this code? 
Actually, I am trying to implement simple image slider on my html page, 
I got error on setInterval function, I cant find it. I try to find out error from console but i cant.

```
<script>
         function slider(){
           $(".slider #1").show("fade" , 500);
           $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:"left"},500);

      var sc = $(".slider img").size();
      var count = 2;

      setInterval(function(){
         $(".slider #"=count).show("slide",{direction:"right"},500);
         $(".slider #"=count).delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:"left"},500);

         if(count == sc){
             count = 1;

         }else{
             count = count+1;
         }
      },5500);



     }
         </script>



</head>
    <body onload="slider()">



        <div class="slider" >
            <img id="1" src="images/slider1.jpg" border="0" alt="slider1">
            <img id ="2" src="images/slider2.jpg" border="0" alt="slider2">
            <img id ="3" src="images/slider3.jpg" border="0" alt="slider3">
            <img id ="4" src="images/slider4.jpg" border="0" alt="slider4">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </body>
```

Console error is: **ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side**

Thanks.

Comment: `$(".slider #"+count)` ....

Comment: Your question is very localized. Don't be surprised if it gets closed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `=count` where you should have `+ count`.

```
$(".slider #" + count).show("slide",{direction:"right"},500);
```

Same with the other line(s).

Comment: can some provide me the working demo on js fiddle its urgent for me

Answer (score 1):

Change '=' to '+'

```
 $(".slider #"+count).show("slide",{direction:"right"},500);
 $(".slider #"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:"left"},500);
```